# {MARKLOGIC} How can I test a view function of docs on a particular role and not admin role on the same document?

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-9, multiple-users

I have a database in MarkLogic and I'm using the query console to control it. I've inserted a few documents and want to view those documents by logging in as a different user on the same db. How can I enable the contributor role to perform limited functions like view?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`xdmp:eval`](http://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:eval):

```
xdmp:eval(
    'fn:doc("/my/uri.json")',
    (),
    map:new((
      map:entry("user-id", xdmp:user("some-user"))
    ))
)
```

As noted in the docs, running this way does require privileges itself, but if you're running in Query Console as admin, you can use this to check what a low-privileged user can do.